# Expression for a very specific utility post climbing gear called "maneas"/"pretal" in spanish, widely used in South America

Tags: expressions, nouns

IMPORTANT, first just watch 30 seconds of 1 or 2 of this YouTube videos featuring the use of "maneas", to visualize this devices: [1](https://youtu.be/xvw-ka-L5Zg?t=108),[2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gC8mKICltM),[3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FGax-3-GCk),[4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YaC8UCTtcCA), don
Pictures [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQC86.jpg),[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP5gh.jpg)

I know this site is not spanish oriented, however, in this post spanish language is used merely as a tool for trying to translate the concept/device/tool "manea" into an english expression. Spanish knowledge is NO NEEDED AT ALL to answer, read, or understand this question.

First "manea"="pretal", they are just 2 spanish words used for this device. I'll use "manea" from now on to simplify.

The expression I'm looking refers to a device, which is simply a rope that, by doing a "cow hitch" knot to a utility post, allows the user, while stepping on the foot part of the "manea", and while alternatively resting the user weight on one of the 2 maneas, while lifting the other, to climb a utility post. It's used by linemans, to do electrical lines work on utility posts.

I have found that in english speaking countries, specially USA and Australia (that's the countries my research results shown mostly) this other system is used: called climbing gaffs, hooks, elevators, climbers [this timestamp video starts right when he climbs](https://youtu.be/uubRVFStIFo?t=242) AND [8](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=climbing%20spikes&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR10.TRC1.A0.H0.Xclimbing%20spikes%20pole.TRS1&_nkw=climbing%20spikes%20pole&_sacat=0)